# $_POST is not returning anything in PHP

Tags: php, post

I have _header.tpl inside inc folder here is full path C:\WebServerN\home\localhost\www\e-test.ru\inc\templates\default_header.tpl
Inside _header.tpl I added

```
    <td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
              <form action="init.inc.php" method='post'>
              <select name="switchlanguage" id="switchlanguage"> 
              <option value="en" >English</option>
              <option value="ru" >Русский</option>
              <option value="tj" >Точики</option> 
              </select> 
        </form>
        </td>
```

In order to make dropdown listbox for language switching. What I want is to get "en", "ru", "tj" if they are chosen.
I have init.inc.php here is full path C:\WebServerN\home\localhost\www\e-test.ru\inc\init.inc.php
I want to switch code according to chosen value. Here is my code in init.inc.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['switchlanguage']))
  {
  include_once($DOCUMENT_LANG.'en.lng.php');
  }
  else
  {
  include_once($DOCUMENT_LANG.$_POST['switchlanguage'].'.lng.php');
  }
```

I am new in PHP, I need your help. Please give me some direction or will be better if you provide me some codes.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have anything that submits the form?  Like a button or some javascripts?

Comment: do you have a submit button (<input type="submit">)? try print_r($_POST); in PHP to see everything that is posted

Comment: Unrelated security comment: Please do at least `basename($_POST['switchlanguage'])` or other checking of the variable, eg. `if(!isset($_POST['switchlanguage']) || !preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}$/', $_POST['switchlanguage']))`, otherwise you'll open up to a directory traversal security hole.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what it says. It is working on my computer.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the form to METHOD="POST" I *think* GET is default if its undeclared

Comment: No I do not have submit button, do I need it?

Comment: I used POST method, even using GET method did not help me.

Comment: Without a submit button, how are you submitting the form?

Comment: By changing combobox is it possible? I am new in PHP, you should give me advice.

Comment: now, wit submit button it is working, how to make it work without button, on selection change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I did not have submit button. In order to get $_POST I need somehow submit the form. So I could not use button due to design issues. I used auto submit. Here is my code.

```
<td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
          <form  method='post'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
          <option value="en" >English</option>
          <option value="ru" >Русский</option>
          <option value="tj" >Точики</option> 
          </select> 
    </form>
</td>
```

That's it!

Answer (score -1):

Remove all the semicolon you have given in all the option tag end. So your code should be like the below.

```
<td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
          <form action="init.inc.php" method='post'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" id="switchlanguage"> 
          <option value="en" >English</option> 
          <option value="ru" >Русский</option> 
          <option value="tj" >Точики</option> 
          </select> 
    </form>
    </td>
```

Now check it out.

Comment: It's good for other reasons, but it wouldn't affect what ends up in the POST request.